# Is the data relational or the database design?

Tags: database-design, nosql, relational-database

I am a novice in the domain of databases and have stumped into this confusion. I am working on converting the database layer of an offline application from sqlite to IndexedDB. 
Currently the database in SQLite is highly relational. Too many of the queries taking place on this database are join queries. 
As I set out to convert this database into one suitable for IndexedDB (NoSQL) I wonder:

Whether a relational database layout can be reworked and converted into a design which belongs in NoSQL world (which won't require any joins)? In other words, can same data be modelled into a relational database and also a NoSQL database, at the same time. Or relational/non-relational is the property of the data and the data should dictate whether a non-relational database or a relational database is required ?

Comment: This question should not have been closed.  The question of whether or not data is inherently relational or whether relational modeling is just one way of loking at the data has an answer.  The answer is that data is NOT inherently relational.  The ER model was invented precisely to fill this gap.  ER modeling doesn't tilt the analysis towards a relational or non relational solution.  If I had to start with an SQL solution and work my way towards a nosql solution,  I would first reverse engineer the existing solution back to an ER model, then design the nosql database based on that.

Comment: a NoSql solution might use something very different than foreign keys to implement relationships.  Part of reverse engineering to ER is to remove the foreign keys, and replace them with "relationships".  another part is deciding whether these relationships are inherent in the requirments or are merely part of the previously designed solution.

Comment: @WalterMitty thanks! My understanding has been that a NoSQL database is void of relations. In my approach I tried to denormalize the relational design I had. But I found that I could not completely get rid of the relations. I still have ids of entities as references in other entities (foreign keys) and I am afraid that NoSQl wont help by providing no relational integrity constraints. So, I am currently trying to figure out how to get-rid-of or express the relations in NoSQL. Can you please give me some pointers on  "remove the foreign keys, and replace them with "relationships" "...

Comment: A denormalized relational design is still a relational design.  You need to remove the relational bias from your understanding of the requirements.  This is what ER modeling was originally intended to do.  In an original syle ERD, the relationships are expressed by lines between boxes, but not implemented by foreign keys inside the boxes.  There are symbols you can put at either end of lines to indicate "optional" or "many".

Comment: Once you have produced an ERD that expresses the requirements, but not the way those requirements were met in the old SQL solution, your next step is to implement those relationships in your NoSQL environment, using whatever mechanisms your target database provides for thatpurpose. I do not knwo how to do that in your target database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the initial requirement that led you to change the backend DB ? if performance, try using more "powerful" SQL DB engines (MySQL,PostgresQL) and you may gain a x30 ! For existing complex datamodel , NoSQL is not an easy conversion and even not a good choice if non exact matching is implied (unless using scoring mechanism, reverse maps ,so "tricks" that would complexify a bit the client code)

The NoSQL choice generally means you have to define your noSQL model to fit the operations you need to perform on it. So you know what requests you will have to perform on your data , and build your NoSQL model from the requests you expect to be done on it. If the requirements on desired requests change, you may have to recreate your NoSQL model to fit your new requests.

The SQL choice is more flexible letting you operate any operation on exisiting data with low impact on data structure (if any) given the relations are sufficient to obtain the requested data. But in terms of raw performance , it won't compete with NoSQL.

So the eternal choice between flexibility & performance!

With NoSQL => performance over flexibility => more work for handling requirement changes, complex code for complex operations, dedicated client interface & coding .

With SQL => flexibility over performance => less work to handle requirement changes, "normalized" (with the quotes) SQL language hides most of the complexity , "generic" client interface & coding.Performance issues can be mitigated by changing engine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want to have a database modeled in both SQL AND NoSQL, but yes, an SQL schema can be "converted" into NoSQL.  With NoSQL your application defines your schema through it's model classes instead of SQL where you define the schema in the database and then build your models around that.  To account for relationships, you just make one of your fields multi-value, like a hashmap etc... depending on the NoSQL solution you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Relational is a way to model data. Under the relational model, raw data goes through an analysis process called normalization. During normalization, data is separated into entities, relationships and attributes. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model).

Normalization is a reversable process. While it is always possible to do this, it is not always wise. For example, complete denormalization can led to an explosion in the size of the database due to redundant data. There is often also a decrease in the flexibility, and an increase in the processing time, of queries into the database. Inserts become tedious, because all entities are represented in one table. So if entity is enlarged, all entities must be enlarged.